# Can I deploy to iOS devices with macOS Sierra?

Tags: ios

I've always had Windows and I just bought a Mac to upload games to the app store for iOS phones. I have read that I have to have an OS X Mac, but my Mac is macOS Sierra. Did I just waste $2k on a Mac?

Comment: You can create iPhone applications on any recent Mac. Install Xcode, and visit some Swift programming sites. Come back with a specific programming related question.

Comment: macOS is the new name of OS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not, macOS is the new OS X and you can upload your app to app store as long as you have an [Apple Developer's account](http://developer.apple.com/). Learn more about archiving your app and uploading it to the app store [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html) if you are confused.